# How do I open a new fragment from another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener, android-button

I tried making a navigation between fragments. I've got the `NewFragment.java` with the new fragment working. My problem is:

How do I make this `onClickListener` run `NewFragment.java` correctly?

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), NewFragment.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
});
```

FYI: This is from inside a fragment (I don't know if that matters).

Comment: IMPORTANT: When working with fragments, navigations is closely related to host acivity so, you can't justo jump from fragment to fragment without implement that fragment class in host Activity. 

Sample:

`public class MyHostActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyFragmentOne.OnFragmentInteractionListener {`

Also, check your host activity has the next override function:

`
@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {}
`
Hope this helps...

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Add following code in your click listener function,

```
NextFragment nextFrag= new NextFragment();
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
             .replace(R.id.Layout_container, nextFrag, "findThisFragment")
             .addToBackStack(null)
             .commit();
```

The string `"findThisFragment"` can be used to find the fragment later, if you need.

Comment: what will be `Layout_container`?

Comment: can anyone clarify what `Layout_container` should be?

Comment: Layout_container is the id of current fragment.  I would recommend using ((ViewGroup).getView().getParent()).getId() instead of R.id.Layout_container.

Comment: layout_container is the id of view present in activity layout where you want to replace a fragment

Comment: @BTRNaidu Should be: ((ViewGroup)getView().getParent()).getId();

Comment: Very important if you want to actually replace the old fragment and not just display the new one next to the old one: Don't declare any fragments inside the container's (e.g. "Activity1", while the fragments are "A1F1" and "A1F2") xml file (as described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Adding)), instead do it at runtime (as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui#AddAtRuntime)), which also requires the container to be a `FrameLayout` (not an e.g. `LinearLayout`)!

Comment: Kotlin version: ((view as ViewGroup).parent as View).id

Comment: How should i use this line of code in a customadapter class that extends listadapter? i get error getContext() can not be resolved

Answer (score 12):

This is more described code of @Narendra's code,

First you need an instance of the 2nd fragment. Then you should have objects of FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction. The complete code is as below,

```
Fragment2 fragment2=new Fragment2();
FragmentManager fragmentManager=getActivity().getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main,fragment2,"tag");
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Hope this will work. In case you use android***x***, you need getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager().

Comment: and what would `content_main` be?

Comment: @HuwDavies the value of id parent View in host Activity layout file. Example:
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Answer (score 6):

Use this,

```
AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
Fragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: I get error addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView when i use this code inside customadapter that extends from listadapter...how should be changed?

Answer (score 5):

You should create a function inside activity to open new fragment and pass the activity reference to the fragment and on some event inside fragment call this function.

Comment: From inside a fragment you automatically already have a reference to the parent activity. Use getActivity() or if you use onAttach the activity is in the arguments.

Answer (score 3):

My how things do change in 8 years time. If you are using NavigationController in your app this is very simple. In your mobile_navigation.xml file you need to create "from" and "to" fragments. In the "from" fragment add the destination id of the "to" fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="com.yourpackage.FromFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/from_fragment" >
        <action android:id="@+id/action_go"
            app:destination="@id/dest_fragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim"/>
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/dest_fragment"
        android:name="com.yourpackage.ToFragment"
        android:label="To Fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/to_fragment" />
</navigation>
```

Then in your onClick handler call:

```
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_go);
```

This page provides more details including how to set up the destination programmatically.

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);
    UserResult nextFrag= new UserResult();
    this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, nextFrag, null)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();  
}
```

Comment: Where is content_frame? Is a frame layout?

Answer (score 2):

Well my problem was that i used the code from the answer, which is checked as a solution here, but after the replacement was executed, the first layer was still visible and functionating under just opened fragment. My solution was simmple, i added

```
.remove(CourseListFragment.this)
```

the CourseListFragment is a class file for the fragment i tried to close.
(MainActivity.java, but for specific section  (navigation drawer fragment), if it makes more sense to you)
so my code looks like this now :

```
LecturesFragment nextFrag= new LecturesFragment();

                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .remove(CourseListFragment.this)
                            .replace(((ViewGroup)getView().getParent()).getId(), nextFrag, "findThisFragment")
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
```

And it works like a charm for me.

Comment: I guess this is the correct solution. But I faced an exception in this case: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot remove Fragment attached to a different FragmentManager. Fragment FileListFragment{206d1c0} (2d135556-b398-4f1f-a282-ba9b19dad5ae id=0x7f09015c) is already attached to a FragmentManager.

Answer (score 2):

Using Kotlin to replace a `Fragment` with another to  the `container` , you can do

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    activity!!
        .supportFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, NewFragment.newInstance())
        .commitNow()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use this in adapter/fragment all previous methouds are expired now

```
((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new cartFragment()).commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple option is to navigate to the second fragment by defining an action in the `nav_graph.xml` and then use it like this (example for Kotlin):

```js
rootViewOfFirstFragment.someBtn.setOnClickListener{
            Navigation.findNavController(rootViewOfFirstFragment)
                .navigate(R.id.action_firstFragment_to_secondFragment)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Fragment fr = new Fragment_class();
             FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.viewpagerId, fr);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Just to be precise, `R.id.viewpagerId` is cretaed in your current class layout, upon calling, the new fragment automatically gets infiltrated.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Narendra solution...

IMPORTANT: When working with fragments, navigations is closely related to host acivity so, you can't justo jump from fragment to fragment without implement that fragment class in host Activity.

Sample:

`public class MyHostActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyFragmentOne.OnFragmentInteractionListener {`

Also, check your host activity has the next override function:

`@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {}`

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

first of all, give set an ID for your Fragment layout  e.g:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
**android:id="@+id/cameraFragment"**
tools:context=".CameraFragment">
```

and use that ID to replace the view with another fragment.java file. e.g

```
 ivGallary.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          UploadDoc uploadDoc= new UploadDoc();
          (getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                  .replace(**R.id.cameraFragment**, uploadDoc, "findThisFragment")
                  .addToBackStack(null)
                  .commit();
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin simply you can use this,

First: Create new instance of the fragment

```
val newFragment = NewFragment.newInstance()
```

Second: Start the fragment transaction

```
val fragmentTransaction: FragmentTransaction = activity!!.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
```

Third: Replace current fragment with new fragment
( tips: avoid using id of the container view like R.id.fl_fragment, you may face view not find error, just use is at mentioned below)

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(
 (view!!.parent as ViewGroup).id,newFragment
)
```

Final Steps:

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
fragmentTransaction.commit()
```