# Retrieve information from Firebase element clicked in ListView

Tags: android, listview, parsing, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an app where Firebase is used to store and retrieve data. When I retrieve data for the DB I have it displayed in a ListView in a fragment. I can then click on a given element in the list and it opens a details fragment.
Right now, I can only display data from a predetermend node from the DB, but I want to display data from the element I have clicked on. To do this I need to have the nodes unique key extracted and the parsed to the other fragments, so data from the chosen node may be displayed. But I do not know how to do this? Can you help me?

Here is a picture of my DB structure:

[image]

"Song" is the first child in the DB and it is the -L-*****... keys I want to extract.

Here is the code for the SongData element which is the one send to and retrieved from the data base:

```
    public class SongData implements Serializable {

private String songTitel;
private String songArtist;
private String songLanguage;
private String songCode;
private String intentAction;
private int resultCode;

    public SongData(){ }

public SongData(String songTitel, String songArtist){

    this.songTitel = songTitel;
    this.songArtist = songArtist;
}

public SongData(String songTitel, String songArtist, String songLanguages, String songCode){

    this.songTitel = songTitel;
    this.songArtist = songArtist;
    this.songLanguage = songLanguages;
    this.songCode = songCode;
}

public String getSongTitel() {
    return songTitel;
}
public void setSongTitel(String songTitel) {
    this.songTitel = songTitel;
}

public String getSongArtist() {
    return songArtist;
}
public void setSongArtist(String songArtist) {
    this.songArtist = songArtist;
}

public String getSongLanguage() {
    return songLanguage;
}
public void setSongLanguage(String songLanguage) {
    this.songLanguage = songLanguage;
}

public String getSongCode() {
    return songCode;
}
public void setSongCode(String songCode) {
    this.songCode = songCode;
}

public String getIntentAction() {
    return intentAction;
}

public int getResultCode() {
    return resultCode;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "SONG TITLE :" + this.songTitel + "\n SONG ARTIST :" + 
    this.songArtist;
}
    }
```

Here the code from the activity that displays data in a ListView:

```
    public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_SONG_TITLE = "song title";
private static final String ARG_SECTION_ID = "section_id";

private String mSongTitle; //mParam1
private Button btnSearch;
private TextView txtViewSearch;
private EditText editTextSearch;
private ListView listViewSearch;
private SearchAdaptor searchAdaptor;

//For storing list of songs from DB
private ArrayList<String> songArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

private OnFragmentSearchInteractionListener mListener;

public SearchFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param songTitle Parameter 1.
 * @return A new instance of fragment SearchFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static SearchFragment newInstance(String songTitle) {
    SearchFragment fragment = new SearchFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_SONG_TITLE, songTitle);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mSongTitle = getArguments().getString(ARG_SONG_TITLE);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

    //Find elements from view
    btnSearch = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    txtViewSearch = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtViewSearch);
    editTextSearch = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTxtSearch);
    listViewSearch = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewSearch);

    //Array adapter for Array List with songs
   final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, songArrayList);
   listViewSearch.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference songRef = database.getReference("Song");

    songRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            SongData song = (SongData) dataSnapshot.getValue(SongData.class);
            String songString = String.valueOf(song);
            songArrayList.add(songString);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                //Required
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            songArrayList.remove(dataSnapshot.getValue(SongData.class));
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                //Required
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                //Required
        }
    });

    listViewSearch.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long Id) {
            //position is the index of the item, counts from 0
            //Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028786/how-do-i-open-a-new-fragment-from-another-fragment
            SongDetailsFragment songDetailsFragment = new SongDetailsFragment();
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                     .replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, songDetailsFragment,"findThisFragment")
                     .addToBackStack(null)
                     .commit();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Refresh the state of the +1 button each time the activity receives focus.
    /////btnSearch.initialize(PLUS_ONE_URL, PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE);
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentSearchInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentSearchInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentSearchInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentSearchInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

    }
```

Code for the fragment that displays details:

```
    public class SongDetailsFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
// The request code must be 0 or greater.
private static final int PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
// The URL to +1.  Must be a valid URL.
private final String PLUS_ONE_URL = "http://developer.android.com";
// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
private PlusOneButton mPlusOneButton;

private OnSongDetailsFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

private TextView txtViewShowSongTitel;
private TextView txtViewShowSongArtist;
private TextView txtViewShowSongLanguage;
private TextView txtViewShowSongCode;

public SongDetailsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1
 * @return A new instance of fragment SongDetailsFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static SongDetailsFragment newInstance(String param1) {
    SongDetailsFragment fragment = new SongDetailsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_song_details, container, false);

    final TextView txtViewShowSongTitel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TxtViewShowSongTitel);
    final TextView txtViewShowSongArtist = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TxtViewShowSongArtist);
    final TextView txtViewShowSongLanguage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TxtViewShowSongLanguage);
    final TextView txtViewShowSongCode = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TxtViewShowSongCode);

    // Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write
    //Retrieve data for the Firebase Database
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference songRef = database.getReference("Song").child("-L-qBD0S742-EQkVvers");

    songRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            SongData s = dataSnapshot.getValue(SongData.class);

            txtViewShowSongTitel.setText(s.getSongTitel());
            txtViewShowSongArtist.setText(s.getSongArtist());
            txtViewShowSongLanguage.setText(s.getSongLanguage());
            txtViewShowSongCode.setText(s.getSongCode());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            // Getting songData failed, log a message
            Log.w(TAG, "loadSong:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });

    Button btnOK = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
    btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Close SongDetailsFragment and return to previous fragment
           getActivity().onBackPressed();
        }

    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Refresh the state of the +1 button each time the activity receives focus.
    //mPlusOneButton.initialize(PLUS_ONE_URL, PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE);
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

/*@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnSongDetailsFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnSongDetailsFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnSongDetailsFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}*/

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnSongDetailsFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

    }
```

I hope someone in here can help me!

Comment: You need to use `SongDetailsFragment.newInstance("-L-...")` somewhere in there in order to pass the ID from the list into the Fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new String field to store song key in your`SongData` class with `@Exclude` annotation. The exclude annotation will tell Firebase to skip the annotated field when saving/retrieving data.

```
@Exclude
private String key;

public void getKey(){this.key;}
public void setKey(final String key){this.key = key;}
....
```

In your onChildAdded callback, grab the key from DataSnapshot, and save it in your SongData object.

```
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        SongData song = (SongData) dataSnapshot.getValue(SongData.class);
        song.setKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());
        String songString = String.valueOf(song);
        songArrayList.add(songString);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Now you can pass the song's key to your fragment from the selected SongData object by creating an instance as such: `SongDetailFragment.newInstance(selectedSong.getKey())`

**Edit:**
As noted by @Alex Mamo below, you also need to fetch all the songs from Firebase. Right now, you are specifying a single key. Therefore, you will only get one song. Incorporate his answer to build you list, and then instantiate your fragment.

Comment: How do I implement selectedSong? I tried with 

        String selectedItem = (String) listViewSearch.getItemAtPosition(position);
                SongDetailsFragment songDetailsFragment1 = SongDetailsFragment.newInstance(selectedItem.getKey());

But it seems to be wrong. I am doing it in the onItemClick().

Comment: In your OnListItemClickListener, use the adaptor position to get the corresponding song by as SongData selectedSong = songArraylist.get(position). Now, you have all the information to instantiate a new fragment with song id.

Comment: I have tried saying:
`View parentRow = (View) view.getParent();

                ListView listView = (ListView) parentRow.getParent();

                position = listView.getPositionForView(parentRow);

                long selectedSong = arrayAdapter.getItemId(position);

                SongDetailsFragment songDetailsFragment = new SongDetailsFragment();
                songDetailsFragment.newInstance(selectedSong.dataSnapShot.getKey());`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You already have the position in `onItemClickListener` in your `SearchFragment`. You do not need to get it again. Just call `SongData selectedSong = songArraylist.get(position); SongDetailsFragment.newInstance(selectedSong.getKey());' Do the usual fragment replace. Also as @Alex Mamo noted below, you need to fetch all the songs. Right now, you are only fetching information for one specific song.

Answer (score 1):

To get all those keys, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference songRef = rootRef.child("Song");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = ds.getKey();
            Log.d("TAG", key);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
songRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The output will be al those generated keys.

Comment: Good catch. I just assumed he was querying properly on Firebase but he was only pulling one song's information.