# Trying to Open fragment from another fragment in android studio 3.5.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I tried to open my second fragment from my 1st fragment but that giving me error.
I tried as [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028786/how-do-i-open-a-new-fragment-from-another-fragment) and I google it everywhere done the same but not worked for me. I also tired with this [android fragment transaction doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions)  but didn't understand. Please can some one explain and solve this error in simpler way. 
Here is my code :

```
            FragmentManager fragmentManager=getActivity().getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.profile_f, new UProfileFragment()); //My second Fragment | & | home_layout is frame layout
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

and Here is my android studio screen error Screenshot :

[image]
Screenshot of exact
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4yoH.png)

Edit : Thank you for your answers this problem was due to androidx library and old android library's code mix up. i was using the old app compact library instead of androidx library. i changed the fragment and function to androidx and it did work. 
Note for new Android developer: please use one compact library's code (either androidx or android old)

Comment: Check the Fragment import. It must be different cause you an error.

Comment: wrong argument type

Comment: use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: ...or just remove `getActivity().` from that line.

Comment: @SantanuSur and Mike Tried both of your code but showing incompatible types . :(

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers and suggestions this problem was due to androidx library and old android library mix up. i was using the old app compact library instead of androidx library. i changed the fragment and function to androidx and it did work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already suggested, use `getSupportFragmentManager()` AND make sure that your `UProfileFragment` inherits from `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` in case you use AndroidX or `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` in case you don't.

Your Activity should inherit from `AppCompatActivity`

Answer (score 2):

try this one code

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.home_layout, new ChatFragment(), "UProfileFragment"); //My second Fragment
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to extend your `UProfileFragment` class with `android.app.Fragment`. Also, you should either use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` or `android.app.Fragment` or `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` if you are using AndroidX.