# Intent not working with companion object using fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, fragment

There is an error in **intent parameters** and could not figure out how to solve this issue.

```
 companion object {
        fun start(context: BookingFragment) {
            context.startActivity(Intent(context, BookingFragment::class.java))
        }
```

//Error:

```
  None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
    public constructor Intent(p0: Context!, p1: Class<*>!) defined in android.content.Intent
    public constructor Intent(p0: String!, p1: Uri!) defined in android.content.Intent
```

Comment: Fragment is not an activity.

Comment: Exactly, to show a fragment in a screen you need a FragmentContainerView -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028786/how-do-i-open-a-new-fragment-from-another-fragment

Comment: @ManuelMato  Can I use like this,     companion object {

        fun start(fragment: BookingFragment, v: View) {
            val activity = v.context as AppCompatActivity
            activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(binding.bookingFragment.id, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null).commit()


        }
    }

Comment: I think has no sense this companion to to the navigation from here.  If your fragment needs arguments, then I understand the companion object to fetch the bundle arguments, but the navigation musn´t be here.  Another weird thing, your fun start(context: BookingFragment) receive a BookingFragment but if you need to open the screen from another fragment, then it won´t be possible, weird approach